# pyparsing: Grouping guidelines

Tags: pyparsing

pyparsing: The below is the code i put up which can parse a nested function call , a logical function call or a hybrid call which nests both the function and a logical function call. The dump() data adds too many unnecessary levels of braces because of grouping. Removing the Group() results in a wrong output. Is there a guideline to use Group(parsers)?

Also the Pyparsing document does'nt detail on how to walk the tree created and not much of data is available out there. Please point me to a link/guide which helps me write the tree walker for recursively parsed data for my test cases.
I will be translating this parsed data to a valid tcl code.

```
from pyparsing import *
from pyparsing import OneOrMore, Optional, Word, delimitedList,  Suppress

# parse action -maker; # from Paul's example
def makeLRlike(numterms):
if numterms is None:
    # None operator can only by binary op
    initlen = 2
    incr = 1
else:
    initlen = {0:1,1:2,2:3,3:5}[numterms]
    incr = {0:1,1:1,2:2,3:4}[numterms]

# define parse action for this number of terms,
# to convert flat list of tokens into nested list
def pa(s,l,t):
    t = t[0]
    if len(t) > initlen:
        ret = ParseResults(t[:initlen])
        i = initlen
        while i < len(t):
            ret = ParseResults([ret] + t[i:i+incr])
            i += incr
        return ParseResults([ret])
return pa


line        = Forward()
fcall       = Forward().setResultsName("fcall")
flogical    = Forward()

lparen      = Literal("(").suppress()
rparen      = Literal(")").suppress()

arg         = Word(alphas,alphanums+"_"+"."+"+"+"-"+"*"+"/")
args        = delimitedList(arg).setResultsName("arg") 

fargs       = delimitedList(OneOrMore(flogical) | OneOrMore(fcall)  | 
OneOrMore(arg))
fname       = Word(alphas,alphanums+"_")
fcall       << Group(fname.setResultsName('func') + Group(lparen + 
Optional(fargs) + rparen).setResultsName('fargs'))

flogic      = Keyword("or") | Keyword("and") | Keyword("not")
logicalArg  = delimitedList(Group(fcall.setResultsName("fcall")) | 
Group(arg.setResultsName("arg")))
#logicalArg.setDebug()

flogical << Group(logicalArg.setResultsName('larg1') + 
flogic.setResultsName('flogic') + logicalArg.setResultsName('larg2')) 


#logical    = operatorPrecedence(flogical, [(not, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT, 
makeLRlike(2)),
#                                           (and, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, 
makeLRlike(2)),
#                                           (or , 2, opAssoc.LEFT, 
makeLRlike(2))])


line    = flogical | fcall #change to logical if operatorPrecedence is used


# Works fine
print line.parseString("f(x, y)").dump()
print line.parseString("f(h())").dump()
print line.parseString("a and b").dump()
print line.parseString("f(a and b)").dump()
print line.parseString("f(g(x))").dump()
print line.parseString("f(a and b) or h(b not c)").dump()
print line.parseString("f(g(x), y)").dump()
print line.parseString("g(f1(x), a, b, f2(x,y, k(x,y)))").dump()
print line.parseString("f(a not c) and g(f1(x), a, b, f2(x,y, 
k(x,y)))").dump()

#Does'nt work fine yet; 
#try changing flogical assignment to  logicalArg | flogic
#print line.parseString("a or b or c").dump()
#print line.parseString("f(a or b(x) or c)").dump()
```

Comment: Put all your tests into a single multiline string (with triple-quotes), and then pass it to `line.runTests`.

Comment: Unary 'not' will not require `makeLRlike`, only the binary operators need this.

Comment: Thanks Paul. This actually was my first attempt using Python and hence the package pyparsing. Sorry for my ignorance, I found "setParseAction" can be used to process the parsed data.

Comment: Please check out the online docs at https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/, especially the classes `ParserElement` and `ParseResults` - the docs contain about 1000 lines of help docstrings. Also, it looks like you are using Python2 (since your print statements are not print functions), I really encourage you to go straight to Python3. Good luck!